# Trying to install Trity-1 and i get a pip error

Tags: python, linux

Trying to install Trity-1 and i get a pip error. I'm using Linux. Below is the traceback-

```
[*] Loading...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python3-pip

E: Package 'python-pip' has no installation candidate
sh: 1: easy_install: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "install.py", line 31, in <module>
    import pip
ImportError: No module named pip
```

Comment: It seems like you don't have `pip` installed. [Refer here for pip installation in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/install-pip-in-linux/amp/)

Comment: Installing pip is failing, this is the error i get

kali@kali:~$ sudo apt install python-pip
[sudo] password for kali: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python3-pip

E: Package 'python-pip' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `python-pip` exists anymore. Try-

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a full setup of trity in kali linux
step by step

try to write this command line

(1) sudo su (for gaining root permission)
(2) git clone the file of trity
link:git clone https://github.com/aymankhalfatni/Trity.git
then
(3)check the present working DIRS
(4)then there you see the trity folder write "cd Trity"
(5)then you will enter the trity folder, there you may see a file named "README.MD"
(6)write the command cat README.MD there willl be a small information on how to install the file of trity
(7)after reading the file go back and write "install.py"
(8)there you may enter the trity app
(9)write 1 for kali linux
(10)if it shows a error check whether you have python installed in your kali linux or not

FOR INSTASLLING PYTHON ON KALI LINUX

(1) write apt-get install python3
(2)if it says its already  installed then wirte "apt-upgrade python3"
then the error  may be fixed and you can install trity

Answer (score 0):

If there is older version of python ie 2.7.18 remove that

Type >> *sudo apt purge -y python2-minimal*

install version 3.8 ie latest

Type >> *sudo apt install -y python3-pip*

latest version of python is installed!